# Problems with real-valued input deep belief networks (of RBMs)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, rbm

I am trying to recreate the results reported in [Reducing the dimensionality of data with neural networks](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/science.pdf) of autoencoding the [olivetti face dataset](http://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/data/olivettifaces.mat) with an adapted version of the MNIST digits [matlab code](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html), but am having some difficulty. It seems that no matter how much tweaking I do on the number of epochs, rates, or momentum the stacked RBMs are entering the fine-tuning stage with a large amount of error and consequently fail to improve much at the fine-tuning stage. I am also experiencing a similar problem on another real-valued dataset.

For the first layer I am using a RBM with a smaller learning rate (as described in the paper) and with

```
negdata = poshidstates*vishid' + repmat(visbiases,numcases,1);
```

I'm fairly confident I am following the instructions found in the [supporting material](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/science_som.pdf) but I cannot achieve the correct errors.

Is there something I am missing? See the code I'm using for real-valued visible unit RBMs below, and for the whole deep training. The rest of the code can be found [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html).

rbmvislinear.m:

```
epsilonw      = 0.001; % Learning rate for weights 
epsilonvb     = 0.001; % Learning rate for biases of visible units
epsilonhb     = 0.001; % Learning rate for biases of hidden units 
weightcost  = 0.0002;  
initialmomentum  = 0.5;
finalmomentum    = 0.9;


[numcases numdims numbatches]=size(batchdata);

if restart ==1,
  restart=0;
  epoch=1;

% Initializing symmetric weights and biases.
  vishid     = 0.1*randn(numdims, numhid);
  hidbiases  = zeros(1,numhid);
  visbiases  = zeros(1,numdims);


  poshidprobs = zeros(numcases,numhid);
  neghidprobs = zeros(numcases,numhid);
  posprods    = zeros(numdims,numhid);
  negprods    = zeros(numdims,numhid);
  vishidinc  = zeros(numdims,numhid);
  hidbiasinc = zeros(1,numhid);
  visbiasinc = zeros(1,numdims);
  sigmainc = zeros(1,numhid);
  batchposhidprobs=zeros(numcases,numhid,numbatches);
end

for epoch = epoch:maxepoch,
 fprintf(1,'epoch %d\r',epoch); 
 errsum=0;
 for batch = 1:numbatches,
 if (mod(batch,100)==0)
     fprintf(1,' %d ',batch);
 end


%%%%%%%%% START POSITIVE PHASE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  data = batchdata(:,:,batch);
  poshidprobs = 1./(1 + exp(-data*vishid - repmat(hidbiases,numcases,1)));  
  batchposhidprobs(:,:,batch)=poshidprobs;
  posprods    = data' * poshidprobs;
  poshidact   = sum(poshidprobs);
  posvisact = sum(data);

%%%%%%%%% END OF POSITIVE PHASE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  poshidstates = poshidprobs > rand(numcases,numhid);

%%%%%%%%% START NEGATIVE PHASE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  negdata = poshidstates*vishid' + repmat(visbiases,numcases,1);% + randn(numcases,numdims) if not using mean
  neghidprobs = 1./(1 + exp(-negdata*vishid - repmat(hidbiases,numcases,1)));  
  negprods  = negdata'*neghidprobs;
  neghidact = sum(neghidprobs);
  negvisact = sum(negdata); 

%%%%%%%%% END OF NEGATIVE PHASE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  err= sum(sum( (data-negdata).^2 )); 
  errsum = err + errsum;

   if epoch>5,
     momentum=finalmomentum;
   else
     momentum=initialmomentum;
   end;

%%%%%%%%% UPDATE WEIGHTS AND BIASES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    vishidinc = momentum*vishidinc + ...
                epsilonw*( (posprods-negprods)/numcases - weightcost*vishid);
    visbiasinc = momentum*visbiasinc + (epsilonvb/numcases)*(posvisact-negvisact);
    hidbiasinc = momentum*hidbiasinc + (epsilonhb/numcases)*(poshidact-neghidact);

    vishid = vishid + vishidinc;
    visbiases = visbiases + visbiasinc;
    hidbiases = hidbiases + hidbiasinc;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF UPDATES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 end
fprintf(1, '\nepoch %4i error %f \n', epoch, errsum);

end
```

dofacedeepauto.m:

```
clear all
close all

maxepoch=200; %In the Science paper we use maxepoch=50, but it works just fine. 
numhid=2000; numpen=1000; numpen2=500; numopen=30;

fprintf(1,'Pretraining a deep autoencoder. \n');
fprintf(1,'The Science paper used 50 epochs. This uses %3i \n', maxepoch);

load fdata
%makeFaceData;

[numcases numdims numbatches]=size(batchdata);

fprintf(1,'Pretraining Layer 1 with RBM: %d-%d \n',numdims,numhid);
restart=1;
rbmvislinear;
hidrecbiases=hidbiases; 
save mnistvh vishid hidrecbiases visbiases;

maxepoch=50;
fprintf(1,'\nPretraining Layer 2 with RBM: %d-%d \n',numhid,numpen);
batchdata=batchposhidprobs;
numhid=numpen;
restart=1;
rbm;
hidpen=vishid; penrecbiases=hidbiases; hidgenbiases=visbiases;
save mnisthp hidpen penrecbiases hidgenbiases;

fprintf(1,'\nPretraining Layer 3 with RBM: %d-%d \n',numpen,numpen2);
batchdata=batchposhidprobs;
numhid=numpen2;
restart=1;
rbm;
hidpen2=vishid; penrecbiases2=hidbiases; hidgenbiases2=visbiases;
save mnisthp2 hidpen2 penrecbiases2 hidgenbiases2;

fprintf(1,'\nPretraining Layer 4 with RBM: %d-%d \n',numpen2,numopen);
batchdata=batchposhidprobs;
numhid=numopen; 
restart=1;
rbmhidlinear;
hidtop=vishid; toprecbiases=hidbiases; topgenbiases=visbiases;
save mnistpo hidtop toprecbiases topgenbiases;

backpropface;
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, I had forgotten to change the back-propagation fine-tuning script (backprop.m). One has to change the output layer (where the faces get reconstructed) to be for real-valued units. I.e.

```
dataout = w7probs*w8;
```

Comment: Can you explain that a bit? If you have real-valued visible units and binary hidden units, won't you have a binary output? Or do you change the last layer to be a BG layer?